# Can a Self Extracting Zip File read a registry entry?

Tags: zip, registry, inf, sfx

I'm trying to get my website to talk to a friend's program. Think ITunes - one main program with hundreds of thousands of little things installed into it. We don't want to have to create an InstallShield install program for each of those hundreds of thousands of little things.

We have the files grouped into the folder sub-structure.
We have a .REG file for what registry entry needs to be added to see the new folder group.

But is there a way to do a self extracting zip file that reads a registry entry so we know where they installed the original program to be able to dump the new files there as well? I want them to double-click the EXE and click Finish and for everything to work.

(I've been looking into INF and CAB files through IExpress.exe, but haven't found the answer. I remember Package for the Web didn't have an option to read a registry entry, but did let you modify the suggested install path.)

Thanks so much.

Best wishes,
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there a way to do a self extracting zip file that reads a registry entry so we know where they installed the original program to be able to dump the new files there as well? I want them to double-click the EXE and click Finish and for everything to work

Well, yes and no. There are self-extractors that can run a program after extracting all files. DotNetZip, for example, can produce an SFX which can do this.

*Just an aside: a normal SFX is just a zip file, with a "stub" executable merged with it. The stub exe can do anything it wants to do, but the most basic thing it does is extract the files in the zip. When you use DotNetZip to produce an SFX, it embeds its particular stub into the zip. That stub knows how to extract files, and also knows how to invoke a program after extracting. You can also produce your own stub that can do other more exotic things.*

So you *could* use an SFX for your purpose. When run, it would extract, then invoke it's extra program. The program could look in the registry, then move or relocate the extracted files to the appropriate place. Then terminate.

For a different twist, the SFX might have just two files: the program-to-run (the one that reads the registry, and another embedded zip. Then when the SFX runs it generates 2 files. Then it invokes the program-to-run, which reads the registry, then unpacks the contained zip and puts the files into the desired place.

Ok, so you *could* do it.

Should you?

mmm, maybe.  This really *is* an installer, so, you should decide whether you want to use a zip as an installer.  Don't forget, if you use an SFX as an installer, there's no good way to uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **Inno Setup** toolchain? It's a bit better than a bare Self-Extracting ZIP file, it's a setup creation utility. I'm convinced it has got something to put some entry in the Registry, look also at the plugins.

Basically, a self-extracting executable that alters the registry, it's a setup program. So why don't you go for a proper one?

Website: **http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php**